Excel VBA: Does Chart have Alt-txt?
I am grading student excel assignments. I need to determine, using VBA, whether the Excel chart has anything as alternative text.
I've tried many things, none of which worked, to wit:
A6Q15 = ActiveChart.Shapes.Item.AlternativeText
If A6Q15 = "" Then A6Q15 = 0 Else A6Q15 = 10
MsgBox A6Q15

I don't care what they put in the box, as long as they put something in the box.
Thanks!

Here is an example. Note that in future you should post some examples of the "trying" you did, because even just using the macro recorder should have led you to the correct answer here and as a rule you need to show your work when you ask questions as stackoverflow (refer to how-to-ask).
Sub GetAltText()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim q As Long
    
    q = 0
    
    '//Of course here we only look at the first or only chart
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
        If Len(ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).AlternativeText) > 0 Then
            q = 10
        End If
    End If

    Debug.Print q

End Sub

